# Make MediaPlayer continue to play when starting new Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-mediaplayer

I wan't my mediaPlayer to continue playing when the user opens a new Intent to access a menue.

I thought this could be handeled like this:

- Pause the Player
- Put player into the extra bundle
- Pass bundle to new menueIntent
- Let menueIntent call player.start()

But even if this will work, I guess it will suffer from lags.
Is there any way to continue playing background sound when the current intent is paused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why bother so much when you have a thing called `Service`? Just create a `Service`, put your playing code inside it and communicate with the `Service` from any `Activity` you want. You can read more about `Services` [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: @Goot, You're welcome! Please don't forget to accept the answer if you've found it useful.